# Проблема с вычитанием баланса у пользователя

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть код, который с баланса пользователя снимает единицы за каждый пост этого пользователя(сколько снимать зависит от ставки самого поста):

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
 if (is_sticky($post->ID) == true) 
    {
        $postAutorId = $post->post_author;   
        $postAutorId = $postAutorId[0]; //id автора поста

        $rate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_sys_total_ad_cost');
        $rate = intval($rate[0]); // ставка за данный пост

        $balance = get_user_meta($postAutorId, 'balance');
        $balance = intval($balance[0]); //баланс пользователя

        if($balance == '')
        {
            $balance = 0;
        }

        if($balance >= $rate) //Если баланс больше или равно ставке, уменьшаем баланс на ставку
        {
            $balance = $balance - $rate;

            $res = $wpdb->query(
                    " UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = '$balance' WHERE `meta_key`='billing_city' AND `wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = '$postAutorId';"
            ); //Перезаписываем баланс

            echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($balance);
            echo '<pre>';    
        }

        else
        {
            //закрываем пост
            // $wpdb->query(
               //     "UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'pending' WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` = '$postAutorId';"
            // );
        }       
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что, если у одного автора есть два поста, почему то списывается баланс только за последний пост (Например: баланс'100', первый пост '50', второй пост '45'. В итоге у пользователя на балансе останется '55' вместо '5')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Потому что не надо лазить руками в базу!**

Вы получаете данные через `get_user_meta()`, которая кэширует запросы к базе, а лупите в базу "вручную". Потом снова обращаетесь с `get_user_meta()`, получаете кэшированное значение мета-поля (начальное, 100). И так далее.

Возьмите за правило - делать все так, как положено. Если бы вы писали в базу через `update_user_meta()`, все было бы хорошо, потому что эта функция сбрасывает кэш.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А не подскажите, как вывести посты у которых статус `pending`? Просто как я понял WP стандартно выводит посты только со статусом `publish`. Хочу сделать проверку, например если у пользователя баланс стал равен '0' и у всех его постов статус стал `pending`, а потом он пополнил баланс, необходимо сделать так чтобы статус его постов поменялся на `publish`. Поэтому хочу достать все посты со статусом `pending` и проверить, может их автор пополнил баланс

Comment: Пожалуйста, задайте новый вопрос и в нем приведите код, которым вы создаете цикл.

Comment: Разобрался как делать. Спасибо!