# Какие поля за что отвечают в WooCommerce в вариативном товаре

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Стоит задача добавлять товар при нажатии на кнопку, находясь в корзине. С обычным товаром проблем не возникло. Понятно, что за что отвечает. Совсем другое с вариативным товаром.

Через какое поле WooCommerce понимает, какой вид вариации выбран.

В таблице wp_postmeta появляются id вариативного товара, причём post_id одинаковые номера а в поле значение meta_value стоимость разная. Зачем все вариативные товары отображаются все и непонятно, по какому id WooCommerce понимает, какой вариативный товар выбран.

При этом в таблице wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta в поле meta_key появляется неизвестно из чего образующееся значение (у меня pa_razmery), а значение этой строки столбца meta_value 50 . Совсем непонятно, откуда берётся.

Может кто объяснить алгоритм внесения данных при заказе?

Comment: Вы здесь вряд ли получите ответ на свой вопрос, потому что для этого надо прочитать лекцию экранов на пять. Сузьте свой вопрос до конкретики и, согласно правилам сообщества, создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve А пока что я могу дать только несколько советов в виде комментариев.

Comment: 1. Никогда, слышите, никогда, не лезьте в базу. Вам там нечего делать. Тем более, когда вы не понимаете базовых принципов организации базы данных WordPress (метаполя), о чем говорит ваш текст "wp_postmeta появляются id вариативного товара, причём post_id одинаковые номера а в поле значение meta_value стоимость разная". Вот вам простейший пример, почему не надо лазить в базу руками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758108/220220

Comment: 2. Пытаться сделать что-то с товаром, манипулируя только базой - все равно что чинить автомобиль, только меняя в нем колеса. А двигатель? А трансмиссия? Сайт приводится в движение кодом php и js, данные хранятся в базе и куках пользователя (вся корзина в куках!). Ничего вы не сделаете, работая только с базой.

Comment: 3. Изучайте в первую очередь классы и методы WooCommerce. Все делается через них. Именно они обеспечивают правильное сохранение в базе всех сущностей и их состояний. Вам при написании своего, даже довольно сложного дополнения к WooCommerce никогда не понадобятся прямые обращения к базе, это я вам по практике говорю.

Comment: 4. И последнее. Если очень интересно, и для понимания процессов (но не для того, чтобы лазить в базу руками !) можно почитать статью на русском https://habrahabr.ru/post/233479/

Comment: Для бОльшей убедительности я тоже скажу: "Никогда, слышите, никогда, не лезьте в базу"!

Comment: @SeVlad я знал, что ты поддержишь это утверждение ))

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии уважаемые пользователи. Тем не менее я разобрался, для решения моей задачи, что за что отвечает :) Понимал, что мало вероятно получить ответ, который мне поможет так, как вопрос действительно очень расплывчатый и надеялся, что ответ получу, который натолкнёт на решения задачи, которая была при написании вопроса, каменным цветком :)