# Удаляются данные записей в БД при очистки корзины постов Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, acf

Удаляются данные записей в таблице wp_postmeta в БД при очистки корзины постов или обновления(добавления, удаление или редактирования) ACF полей Wordpress.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вывод запроса SQL в админки**

```
var_dump('SELECT post_id,meta_value,meta_key FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' WHERE post_id = 3045');
```

*Результат оригинал(все как нужно):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Результат то что получается после обновлений или редактирования ACF:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*GIF - Очистка корзины.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в этой таблице же различные параметры записей. а в чем проблема то? удаляется что то еще в админке, кроме содержимого корзины?

Comment: @md5hash Удаляются половина нужных данных, то есть обрубается пол таблицы.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблемы из-за того, что ваш код лезет в базу напрямую. Даже в вопросе вместо get_post_meta() я вижу обращение к базе мимо всех кешей.

Comment: Почитайте, почему не надо лазить руками в базу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758108/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign не кто и не лез туда

Comment: Так не бывает. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KAGGDesign и что мне сюда добавить ? Процесс очистки корзины?  Или как я добавил поля в админку?

Comment: Вы вроде не первый день на SO. Создайте такой пример, чтобы я его мог повторить, увидеть ошибку и покопаться в отладчике.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну это понятно, вот только что написать не знаю, просто в один прекрасный момент при очистки корзины, а так же и при попытки изменить поля ACF все данные слетели. Почему так не понятно.  При попытке оптимизации таблицы плагинами, происходит тоже самое.

Comment: @KAGGDesign может как то проверить таблицу wp_postmeta или вообще все  таблицы на целостность/правильность !?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78732/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).