# Wordpress. Изменить содержимое сайдбара с помощью PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

В таблице wp_options, в строке с option_name=widget_text
содержится информация о содержимом виджетов в следующем формате

```
a:2:{i:2;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:7:"title_1";s:4:"text";s:6:"text_1";s:6:"filter";b:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

А строке, где option_name=sidebars_widgets
содержится информация о содержимом сайдбаров, они имеюте такой вид

```
a:7:{s:19:"wp_inactive_widgets";a:0:{}s:9:"sidebar-1";a:6:{i:0;s:8:"search-2";i:1;s:14:"recent-posts-2";i:2;s:17:"recent-comments-2";i:3;s:10:"archives-2";i:4;s:12:"categories-2";i:5;s:6:"meta-2";}s:9:"sidebar-2";a:0:{}s:9:"sidebar-3";a:0:{}s:4:"top1";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"text-2";}s:4:"top2";a:0:{}s:13:"array_version";i:3;}
```

Я не знаю, что означает такое устройство строк, не похоже на JSON
Мне нужна функция, которая принимает в качестве аргументов название сайдбара и его текстового содержимого, создаёт сайдбар

Я знаю, что нужно делать в файле functions.php - добавить строки вида

```
register_sidebar( array(
'name'          => esc_html__( *название нового сайдбара*, 'имя темы' ),
```

Но не знаю, как составить правильный SQL запрос, чтобы сохранить содержимое сайдбара.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Первое правило работы с WordPress - **забудьте про существование базы**. Вам категорически нельзя туда ничего писать руками (своими SQL-запросами). Посмотрите [ответ с простейшим примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758108/220220), к чему это приводит.

Любопытствовать, конечно, можно, но только в режиме чтения.

Данные в WordPress между базой и кодом проходят через кэш, объектный кэш, транзинты. Сломать всё это своей записью в базу - не вопрос. Особенно, когда вы не разбираетесь в форматах сохраняемых данных. А судя по вопросу, дело обстоит именно так.

То, что вы привели - так называемые сериализованные данные. С помощью php-функций `serialize()` / `unserialize()` объекты и массивы преобразуются в строки и обратно. Это стандартный способ хранения агрегированных данных в WordPress, применяется на каждом шагу.

Для работы с базой, да и вообще на все остальные случаи в WordPress есть специальные функции.

Чтобы создать сайдбар, вам нужно поместить такой минимальный код в function.php

```
function register_my_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        // эти два параметра обязательны
        'name' => 'Название сайдбара в админке', // любая строка
        'id'   => 'sidebar-unique-id', // уникальный id сайдбара
    ) );
}
// Функция должна быть вызвана по событию `widgets_init`
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_sidebar' );
```

И это всё, что от вас нужно. Остальные действия WP произведёт сам. Вы увидите в админке новый сайдбар, в который можно будет добавить виджет.

В шаблоне страницы / категории и т.п. вывод сайдбара производится так:

```
if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') )
    dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-unique-id');
```

И никаких манипуляций с базой вручную.