# WP: обновить у комментариев мета поле sql запросом

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице поста, т.е. в цикле, необходимо при загрузке страницы пройтись по комментариям и изменить определённое мета поле (именно изменить, если оно есть) у всех комментариев, обладающих им. Работать с функцией `update_comment_meta` не получится:

- Функция будет создавать мета поле, если его нет у комментария
- Насколько я понял каждый вызов - обращение к БД. Так себе перспектива по нагрузке

Думаю, будет лучше одним sql запросом пройтись по комментариям текущего поста (передать `$comment_post_ID`), найти комментарии с нужным мета полем и если в значении мета поля стоит `1`, то выставить `0` (или `true/false` - без разницы).

Насколько я понимаю, сначала надо залезть в таблицу с комментариями (`wp_comments`), собрать все ID комментариев текущего поста, после с этим массивом ID'шников пройтись по таблице `wp_commentmeta` и выполнить обновление.

Требуется помощь с составлением запроса.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = '
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( comment_ID ) AS ids
    FROM  `wp_comments` 
    WHERE comment_post_ID =  '.%ТУТ_ID_ПОСТА%;

    $ids = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ????);
```

В `get_results` в каком виде вернуть данные `OBJECT` или `ARRAY_A`? Начало правильное? А дальше как?

Comment: Никогда не лазьте руками в базу! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758108/220220

Comment: Все ваши комментарии **одним** запросом вытащит функция get_comments(). Потом надо пройтись по постам комментариев, посмотреть их мета поля с помощью get_comment_meta(). Если поле есть, то обновить. Покскольку все **тотально** кешируется, проблем не будет.

Comment: @KAGGDesign т.е. `get_comments()`, полученные данные прогнать через  `foreach`, внутри цикла условие `if (get_comment_meta) { update_comment_meta}`?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а если на архивной странице, т.е. список постов через цикл WP_Query в краткой версии поста нужны получить все комментарии этого поста с определенным мета полем. Мне внутри цикла wp_query запускать get_comments с передачей post_id? Это единственный правильный метод?

Comment: да, это вполне себе нормальный метод